# React not updating component props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It seems that my component props are not updated the way I thought they ought to be.

```
var AdditionalInfoBlock = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return ({
            comment: this.props.comment
        });
    },

    onCommentChange: function(e) {
        this.setState({comment: e.target.value});
        this.props.onCommentChange(e);
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <ToolBlock>
                <div className="container">
                    <form>
                        <textarea value={this.props.comment} onChange={this.onCommentChange} />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </ToolBlock>
        );
    }
};

var MainTool = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            comment: undefined
        };
    },

    restart: function (e) {
        e && e.preventDefault && e.preventDefault();
        this.setState(this.getInitialState());
    },

    onCommentChange: function(e) {
        this.setState({
            comment: e.target.value
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <AdditionalInfoBlock comment={this.state.comment}
                                     onCommentChange={this.onCommentChange} />
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

What I want this code to do is basically hold the comment's value until I post it and call `restart` - then it should reset the value in both `AdditionalInfoBlock` and `MainTool`. At the moment after `restart` is called when I `console.log()` the state of `MainTool`, the `comment` value is undefined. However, if I log `AdditionalInfoBlock` state and/or props, then the `comment` value is not reset in neither of those.

(PS. This is obviously a short version of the code, hopefully only incorporating the relevant bits. Although `restart` is not called in this excerpt, it doesn't mean that I have forgotten to call it at all :))

Comment: Try accessing the state in `componentDidUpdate()` instead of accessing it exactly after your `setState`. And https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html

Comment: I'm not following entirely, could you elaborate on how that would solve my  issue? The main problem is that in `<textarea value={this.props.comment} onChange={this.onCommentChange} />` `this.props.comment` returns the previous prop value although a new one has been assigned in the parent object (should return `undefined` but returns whatever was there before calling `restart`).

Comment: I just got confused with too many component handling the same `state`. I don't think the `textbox value` property accepts `undefined` as an argument, try setting the `initialState` into an empty string or in your `restart()` method, `this.setState({comment: ''});`

Comment: Tried that already before posting, but as stated in the original post, the problem lies elsewhere - `console.log(this.state.props)` does not return `undefined` either, but the previous value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're handling the same state on both components `MainTool` and `AdditionalInfoBlock`, finding value of the comment can get confusing. While you're listening for the comment change, you're setting the state on both components.

The changed state in your parent component `MainTool` is passing the props to the child `AdditionalInfoBlock`. `getInitialState` is invoked once before `mounting` ([`getInitialState` documentation](https://jsfiddle.net/ta8y1w1m/)). Therefore, the passed on property is not handled by you child component on succeeding updates. By using `componentWillReceiveProps`, you will be able to handle the `props` sent by `MainTool`.

```
var AdditionalInfoBlock = React.createClass({
    ...

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
            this.setState({comment: nextProps.comment});
    },
```

**Working Code:** https://jsfiddle.net/ta8y1w1m/1/

Comment: amazing, really helpfull, strange that in several same threads I am not found this answer, thanks